# ERROR ReferenceError: WebSdk is not defined - digitalpersona

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a problem with the digitalpersona sdk.

```
CrearempleadosComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:1  ERROR ReferenceError: WebSdk is not defined
    at new Channel (channel.js:10:1)
    at new FingerprintReader (reader.js:21:1)
    at CrearempleadosComponent.cargarLector (crearempleados.component.ts:557:19)
    at CrearempleadosComponent.ngOnInit (crearempleados.component.ts:97:10)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328:36)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271:1)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CrearempleadosComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:1:1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrjTd.png)

I've added the module/WebSdk folder to the project, I've installed libraries. In another project it works, but now it isn't working and I don't know what to do

Comment: Good thing you posted the error as a screenshot as well as readable version. Makes this question twice as unlikely to be solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that language. English is required for all content on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions#:~:text=English%20is%20required%20for%20all,comments%2C%20and%20even%20chat%20messages.)

Answer (score 0):

I already find the solution.

1. To add all @digitalpersona libraries (npm) [https://www.npmjs.com/~digitalpersona](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Edigitalpersona)
2. Into angular.json -> scripts section, to add "src/modules/WebSdk/index.js"
3. In src creating a folder with the name modules and into that the Websdk folder: https://github.com/hidglobal/digitalpersona-devices/tree/master/%40types/WebSdk that files.
4. Building the project and to fix type="Websdk" errors (comment it)
5. Building again